# How can achieve concurrency in reading two files at a time and do something with the data fetched

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

Problem: i will be provided two files containing urls(assume equal amount of urls in both files), i have to get each url from each file make a request and compare their responses

Right now i have achieved this by getting reading each line and firing request using 'requests' Module
        f1 = open(FileHandler.File1path,'rt')
        f2 = open(FileHandler.File2path,'rt')

```
    def compareresponse(f1,f2):
      for url1,url2 in zip(f1,f2):
            resp1 = requests.get(url1.rstrip(),headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
            resp2 = requests.get(url2.rstrip(),headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
                if(resp1.text==resp2.text):
                    print(url1.rstrip()+ " equals " + url2.rstrip())
                else:
                    print(url1.rstrip() + " notequals " + url2.rstrip())
```

How can i execute this in parallel , where, while I am waiting for response i can send another HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

Use `threading` module, or define `async` function.
example:

```
import requests
from threading import Thread
results = []
def getter(url):
    r = requests.get(url.rstrip(), headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    results.append(r.text)
    if len(results) is 2:
        # continue your code when all requests are responded
        pass
Thread(target=getter, args=(url1,)).start()
Thread(target=getter, args=(url2,)).start()
# or use for ...
```

Comment: i will have to compare the value of  URL1's 'r.text' with URL2's 'r.text' , how do it do that

Comment: Those texts are now element of `results` array. So url1r.text is `results[0]` & url2r.text is `results[1]`.